# Is there a way to find if the user is typing while the app is in background in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I understand it is not possible to get touch events that happen outside the app. But I wanted to know if there is any other way to detect this. It is possible to detect a dragging action from outside the app. I was wondering if something similar can be used? Any help would be great!!

Comment: The answer is simple: no, you can't.

Comment: is it possible to get the touch sensor values similar to getting the accelerometer values? I'm desperate here :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be security and app review concerns caused by this but contrary to popular opinion, it is not "impossible". Try following:

1. Use Appium java API. First launch a dummy app, then call
   `driver.back()` and from there, you will have full control.
2. There is this this tool called **Seetest**. They somehow do these touch events without Jailbreak. Check this out: youtu.be/RkSp8u-TzII?t=1m30s

Comment: I have to distribute the app through the appstore. So, is this against the guide lines?